# "InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: This transaction is already finalized."

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have gone through lots of questions might be its repeat question.:(

exception i got -**"message":

> "InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: This transaction is already
>   finalized. Transactions are committed after its success or failure
>   handlers are called. If you are using a Promise to handle callbacks,
>   be aware that implementations following the A+ standard adhere to
>   run-to-completion semantics and so Promise resolution occurs on a
>   subsequent tick and therefore after the transaction commits."**

in React native android app i am getting values from offline data for appointment. in which i have done the lazy loading. my appointment limit is 10.

i have a flat list and i am checking the flatlist **onEndReached** properties.

in onEndReached properties i am getting the values from local database here is my function through which i am getting offline appointment values

```
  GetAllAppointment(data) {
    console.log("DATA IN -------->>", data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.initDB().then((db) => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {

          getObj('skipRecord', (id) => {

           var skipRecord = ((data.pageNumber - 1) * 10);

            let userAppointmentList = [];
            tx.executeSql("Select * from ios_Appointment where date >= " + nowDate + " and clinicianId =" + data.UserID + " and  fName Like '%" + data.searchKey + "%' OR lName Like '%" + data.searchKey + "%' OR address Like '%" + data.searchKey + "%' ORDER BY (date)").then(([tx, results]) => {
              if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                for (let i = skipRecord; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                  userAppointmentList.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }
              }
              let pages;
              pages = results.rows.length / records;
              pages = Math.ceil(pages)
              let items = {
                "Version": "1.2.3",
                "StatusCode": 200,
                "Message": "Success",
                "Result": userAppointmentList,
                "pagesCount": pages
              }

              resolve(results);

            }).then((result) => {
              // this.closeDatabase(db);
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log("GetAllAppointment 1---->>", err);
            });
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("GetAllAppointment 2---->>", err);
          });
        }).catch((err) => {
        });
      }
```

i am calling above function to dashboard page where i am adding this return appointment to Flalist

```
const db = new Database();
export default class DashboardPage extends Component {
this.page = 1;
.
.
.
handleLoadMore = () => { 
       if (!this.state.showLoader && (this.state.pageCount > this.page)) {
         console.log("handleLoadMore page if------------------>>> ", this.state.showLoader);
         this.page = this.page + 1;
         this.setState({ showBottomLoader: true });
         this.getData(page);
      }
.
.
.
 getData(body) {

              let body = {
                  "pageNumber": page,
                  "searchKey": this.state.searchText,
                  "UserID": 1,
                  "currentDate": new Date().getTime()
               }


      db.GetAllAppointment(body).then((item) => {
         let newData;
         if (item) {
            if (body.pageNumber == 1) {
               newData = item.Result;
               this.state.appointmentList.concat(item.Result)
            } else {
               newData = this.state.appointmentList.concat(item.Result)
            }


            this.setState({
               showLoader: false,
               appointmentList: newData,
               pageCount: item.pagesCount,
               showBottomLoader: false,
               isRefreshing: false
            })
         }
      }).catch((err) => {
         this.setState({
            showLoader: false,
            appointmentList: newData,
            pageCount: item.pagesCount,
            showBottomLoader: false,
            isRefreshing: false
         })
      })
```

first time i am getting 10 records but then i am getting the DOM exception how to solve this problem :(
thanks in advance

Comment: any idea :( why this exception comes and how to catch this exception in **GetAllAppointment** method ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally its solved.

```
 GetAllAppointment(data) {
    console.log("DATA IN -------->>", data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.initDB().then((db) => {
        getObj('skipRecord', (id) => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
```

before transaction i am checking my skip-record value which is stored locally and then upon id executing the db.transaction
now finally stop getting the DOM Exception :)